# HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation Spring boot

Tags: json, spring, web-services, spring-boot, jackson

I have created one service using Spring boot using the following dependency

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
```

Now in my controller class I have written the following:

```
@RestController
 @RequestMapping("/abc")
 public class WebController {



    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{value}", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces =  {"application/json", "application/xml" })
        public ResponseEntity<Ack> getTest(@PathVariable("value") String value) {
            Ack ack = new Ack();
            ack.setResponse(value);
            ack.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
            return new ResponseEntity<Ack>(ack, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
}
```

Ack is the POJO and it has setters and getters for each of the properties.

When I am running this in Windows machine I am getting out put in both json and XML format. But in Mac when using postman I am hitting the service using the URL: http://IP:8443/abc/test/123 and providing accept as application/xml I am getting the output in XML format. When I using application/json I am getting the error like:

```
org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:260)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:203)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:381)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
```

Not sure what went wrong. Please suggest what to do.

Comment: probably you don't have jackson in your classpath. Jackson converts your pojo to json, which is missing I believe. hence this exception. Add jackson to your pom

Comment: jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.10.jar and jackson-core-asl-a.9.10.jar are there in the class path. In windows it's working fine. But in mac it is able to produce output in xml but in json showing the error as mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I figure out that the jackson api version which I was was using, (mentioned below)

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

is not able to provide JSON output although when I use ,

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

it worked like a charm. I am marking this as a solution to my problem posted above, but still not able to find out why?? Why in windows it worked and why it fails in Mac. Gray area for me.. !!!